# How to hide the automatic generated moc_, autouic_ and ui_ files in VisualStudion 2022?

Tags: visual-studio, qt, visual-c++, moc

I'm working on a CMake project that uses Qt. To automatically generate MOC and UI files, I've set the CMAKE_AUTOMOC and CMAKE_AUTOUIC options to ON in my CMakeLists file. As a result, Visual Studio displays automatically generated files with names like "autoic_", "moc_" and "ui_" and some automatic generated directories that contain files I don't need to edit.

My question is, how can I hide these directories and files in Visual Studio without disabling CMAKE_AUTOMOC and CMAKE_AUTOUIC? I need to keep these options on to build my project correctly.
[image: The automatic generated files]

I tried to set CMAKE_AUTOMOC and CMAKE_AUTOUIC to OFF but in this case my project can't build.

Answer (score 0):

I met the same problem in vs2017，haven't found a solution to this problem yet。
Here's how to hide a folder：

```
source_group("CMake Rules" REGULAR_EXPRESSION"^$")
source_group("Header Files" REGULAR_EXPRESSION"^$")
source_group("Source Files" REGULAR_EXPRESSION"^$")
```

Not sure how to hide files。

Comment: Is it possible to use vs2022's custom CMake build setup tool to reverse-find a way to hide these files.

Comment: These files can be deposited into another filter this way：source_group("Other" REGULAR_EXPRESSION "\\.h$|\\.cpp$|\\.stamp$|\\.rule$")